# Return JSON Data with Springs MVC which way is better and why

Tags: java, web-services, spring, rest, spring-mvc

Return JSON Data with Springs MVC which way is better and why? Should I sent back ResponseEntity or just the Object?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public User getDisplayDefault(ModelMap model)
{
    return new User("realname", "john smith");
}
```

**vs**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<User> getDisplayDefault(ModelMap model)
{
   return new ResponseEntity<User>(new User("realname", "john smith"), HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
}
```

Comment: Your first option will normally result in a 200 OK. Is that what you want?

Comment: you dont need to use @ResponseBody in the second case. Second case is better and usefule in cases like  handle exceptions, setting redirect headers etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second option gives you greater control of the response that is returned ... status codes and header parameters can be altered.

For most cases the first option is enough and is simpler; and if you have to ask you probably want the first option.